# Is It possible to force operator **default(MyStructType)** initialize struct with predefined values

Tags: c#, default, default-value

I have a struct type:

```
struct test1
{            
  public int a;
  public int b;
  public double c;
  public string d;
}
```

following line gives me "clear" struct object wich fields was initialized with their default values:

```
test1 tt = default(test1);
// tt.a will be equal 0
```

But now, I desire to have opportunity predefine default values for some fields in the struct type. For example, I want field **a** to have **25** as a default value.

Is it possible to force **default** operator initialize my struct with **my predefined default values**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

The different types already have clear defaults:

- `null` for reference types.
- 0 or 0.0 for integer and float types.

I believe that the default `DateTime` is simply the interpretation of the above for its internal fields (0 * 100 nanoseconds from epoch).

You can't override or change how the `default` operator works.

Answer (score 1):

Your fields will be initialized to the default value for their type, but you can use a property to make it behave as if it was setting default values.

In this snippet we use a nullable int but expose an int.  If the value of the backing field is null we know that we are dealing with a new/default instance and need to provide default values.

```
    struct test1
    {
        private int? a;

        public int A
        {
            get { return a ?? 25; }
            set { a = value; }
        }
    }
```